# Dfs in image pixel

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I'm Practicing Dfs with this Image, and I want to count the white spot in the Image 
[image]

but the dfs ends up like this

[image: but the dfs ends up like this]

```
def dfs(img,j,i,width,height):
    print(j,i)
    if j < 0 or i< 0 or j>= height or i>= width or (img[j,i,0] == 0 and img[j,i,1] == 0 and img[j,i,2] == 0):
        cv2.imshow("hi",img)
        cv2.waitKey(0) 
        return 
    img[j,i,0] = 0
    img[j,i,1] = 0
    img[j,i,2] = 0


    dfs(img,j+1,i,width,height)
    dfs(img,j-1,i,width,height)
    dfs(img,j,i+1,width,height)
    dfs(img,j,i-1,width,height)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    img = cv2.imread(r"D:\secret\Problem3\test2-gray.bmp")

    count = 0
    img = cv2.resize(img, (400, 400), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    og_img = img.copy()
    width,height = img.shape[0],img.shape[1]
    for j in range(height):
        for i in range(width):
            if (img[j,i] >0).all():
                count += 1
                dfs(img,j,i,width,height)
    cv2.imshow("hi",img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I think there is something wrong with the end statement in the dfs, but can't figure it out, can someone give me a hint? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hit the recursion limit of Python. You could try to set it higher with
https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit
but a better option is to handle the recursion stack yourself, e.g.:

```
def dfs(img,j,i,width,height):
    todo = [(j,i)]
    while todo:
        j,i = todo.pop()
        if not (0 <= j < height) or not (0 <= i < width) or (img[j,i] == 0).all():
            continue
        img[j,i,0] = 0
        img[j,i,1] = 0
        img[j,i,2] = 0
        sz += 1
        todo += [(j+1,i), (j-1,i), (j,i+1), (j,i-1)]
```

Comment: well, after tracking, it is really the problem of recursion limit,not my algorithm, thanks! maybe using recursion isn't a proper way in this problem

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you re-visit pixels you have already processed. Since you set them to '0' (black), the `dfs` function returns before it visited all white pixels.

Try to use a `set()` or something to keep track of already visited pixels, and then check for each pixel if it is already in the set.

Example for your loop:

```
  for j in range(height):
        for i in range(width):
            visited_pixels = set()
            if (img[j,i] >0).all():
                count += 1
                visited_pixels.add((j, i))
                dfs(img,j,i,width,height, visited_pixels)
```

Then, in the function:

```
def dfs(img,j,i,width,height, visited_pixels):
    if (j, i) in visited_pixels:
        return
    if (your_if_statement)
    ...
    visited_pixels.add(j, i)
```